# how to replace non-numeric chars using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am wondering how to use regex remove any non-numeric chars while only selecting non-empty and spaces (a single value may contain one or multiple spaces) values for a series in a more efficient way,

```
df['numeric_no'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x))
df = df[(df['numeric_no'] != '') & (df['numeric_no'] != ' ')]
```

some sample data for the `df`

```
numeric_no
B-27000
44-11-E
LAND-11-4
17772A
88LL9A
321LP-3
UNIT 9 CAM -00-12
WWcard_055_34QE
EE119.45
aaa
b  b
```

the result will look like

```
numeric_no
27000
4411
114
17772
889
3213
90012
05534
119.45
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: @jezrael sample data has been added

Comment: Thank you, so all rows are selected? No one removed from sample?

Comment: @jezrael just added sample result, hope it is clear

Comment: Try [`re.sub(r"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|.", "$1", x)`](https://regex101.com/r/BW749d/1)

Comment: @daiyue - answer was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df['numeric_no'].str.findall("(\d*\.\d+|\d+)").str.join('')

s = s[s.astype(bool)]
print (s)

0     27000
1      4411
2       114
3     17772
4       889
5      3213
6     90012
7     05534
8    119.45
Name: numeric_no, dtype: object
```

Comment: I think this is what OP needs but still needs some clarification

Answer (score 1):

You could match and capture numbers and match any thing else:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|.
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/BW749d/1)

Then replace match with `$1` (a back-reference to first capturing group)

Python code:

```
re.sub(r"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|.", "$1", x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think can try:

```
df.numeric_no.str.extractall('(\d+?[\.\d+])').astype(str).sum(level=0)
```

Output:

```
        0
0    2700
1    4411
2      11
3    1777
4      88
5      32
6    0012
7    0534
8  119.45
```

Comment: Are you meaning `\d+` in a character class? or each one separately? `\d`, `+`?